# Why is concat reformatting my headings?

Tags: csv, pandas, append, concatenation

I have sorted a `CSV` file as I want it and appended a column to sort my data properly. However, in using `concat` (I think this is where the issue is, anyway) The output `CSV` file has been changed to (0L, 'HeadingTitle'). I just want it to be HeadingTitle.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3

data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('MYDATA.csv')
byqualityissue = data.groupby(["CompanyName","QualityIssue"]).size()
df = pd.DataFrame(byqualityissue)

formatted = df.unstack(level=-1)
formatted[np.isnan(formatted)] = 0

includingtotals = pd.concat([formatted,pd.DataFrame(formatted.sum(axis=1),columns=['Total'])],axis=1)
sorted = includingtotals.sort_index(by=['Total'], ascending=[False])
#del sorted['Total']
sorted.to_csv('byqualityissue.csv')
```

Where the output headings are:

`CompanyName, (0L, 'Equipment'),  (0L, 'User'),   (0L, 'Neither'),    Total`

How do I modify this so that I only have the heading titles?

Edit:
If I print sorted.columns the output is

```
Index([(0, u'Equipment), (0, u'User'), (0, u'Neither'), u'Total'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Could you include a minimal sample from `MYDATA.csv` that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: I don't have an answer for why, but the column headers are tuples with a zero stored as a long as the first element of the tuple. I've not seen that before. some example data might be helpful.

Comment: @mcwitt, I have added a screenshot of what the MYDATA csv looks like as an example. Does this example data help?

Comment: What do the columns of `sorted` look like? Can you add `print sorted.columns` to your script and include the output?

Comment: @mcwitt added the requested sorted.columns output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(byqualityissue)
```

you don't give the column a name, so it takes the default value `0`.
Then when you call `unstack`,

```
formatted = df.unstack(level=-1)
```

the result has hierarchical columns with `0` in the first level. To fix this you can substitute the previous line with

```
formatted = df.unstack(level=-1)[0]
```